# I can't search by Date from java application by MySQL when use jcalender?

Tags: java, mysql

```java
try {
         JasperDesign jd=JRXmlLoader.load("C:\\Users\\Netcom\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Hamody\\ReportD.jrxml");                          // Full address of you Report in between the “”
//         String sql = " SELECT * FROM `movie` WHERE acc_num =" + search.getText().toString()+" "; // للبحث عن نص او رقم
//           String sql = " SELECT * FROM `movie` WHERE acc_num =" +jComboBox1.getSelectedItem() .toString()+" "; // للبحث عن نص او رقم

          String sql = " SELECT * FROM `movie` WHERE `date` = "+jDateChooser3.getDate()+" ";
          JRDesignQuery newQuery=new JRDesignQuery();
          newQuery.setText(sql);
          jd.setQuery(newQuery);

         JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jd);
         JasperPrint jasperprint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, null,con);
         JRViewer v = new JRViewer (jasperprint);
         jPanel2.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
         jPanel2.add(v);

        } catch (JRException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Reportd.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

        } 


  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mysql uses 'YYYY-MM-DD' format to store date. So you will need to use a formatter to format the date that you are getting from **jDateChooser3.getDate()**

replace the below line

String sql = " SELECT * FROM `movie` WHERE `date` = "+jDateChooser3.getDate()+" ";

with

**String sql = " SELECT * FROM `movie` WHERE `date` = "+new SimpleDateFormatter("YYYY-MM-DD").format(jDateChooser3.getDate())+" ";**